# Largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers

Tags: combinations, palindrome, project-euler

I am doing a python problem and I need to find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers. So, how would I get all possible combinations?

I imagine it is multiplying all combinations of 100 to 999 but am a bit stuck on how to do this. I hope this makes sense.

```
    def genYieldThreeValues(stop):
    j = 999
    while stop >99 and j > 99:
        multiples = str(stop * j)
        front = multiples[:3] # get front three numbers
        back = multiples[-3:] # get last three numbers
        stop-=1
        j-=1
        yield  [front,back,multiples] # yield a list with first three, last three and all numbers

    def highestPalindrome(n):
    for x in genYieldThreeValues(n):
        if   x[1] ==x[0][::-1]: # compare first three and last three digits reversed
            return x[2]         # if they match return value

    print(highestPalindrome(999))
```

Comment: This is [Project Euler, number 4](http://projecteuler.net/problem=4)

Comment: You might consider generating palindromes and then factoring.

Comment: @Zook I did this in October '13!

Comment: ah, looks like @Ross just raised it from the dead.

Comment: Yes, I was a bit lost as to the comment also as it is  stated in the answer that it is for Euler.

Comment: No, it was raised from the dead before my comment.

Comment: must be ghosts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you've started [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/problem=4)?

Since you are asked for the **largest** palindrome from two 3-digit numbers, then why not start two loops and cycle downwards:

```
for i in range(999,100,-1):
    for j in range(999,100,-1):
       product = i*j
```

Then you just have to reverse it & compare the `product` with the `reverse`. There is an easy way to do this in Python, but part of PE is that you figure it out for yourself :).

Comment: I have indeed, I was trying to do it using a generator so it could be used on very large numbers, I am a bit lost on the maths behind getting the combinations, getting late and I have been staring at this for probably too long!(added my code to show where I am lost)

Comment: If it is going too slow, remember that all palindromes with an even number of digits have a common factor, so either $i$ or $j$ is a multiple of that.

Comment: @Michael do i need to calculate every possible product to get  the answer? If so in mathematical terms how do you get every possible outcome of multiplying two sets of numbers from 100 to 999?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Once you have found one that works, you don't need to check any smaller numbers.  That is why Kyle suggested starting from the top.  If you were to discover that 918819 were the product of two three digit numbers (it is not), you wouldn't have to check factors smaller than what?

Comment: @ron by starting at 999 in my code am I not starting at the higher possible values, I think I must be over complicating this in my head!

Comment: I think you are making it far more complicated than necessary @PadraicCunningham. You need to multiply two numbers together$\to$see if they make a palindrome$\to$check if it's the largest possible palindrome. Clearly if you start from the top (999), then you are going to find the largest more quickly.

Comment: @KyleKanos thanks, I think I need to sleep and readdress it tomorrow refreshed, thanks again